# How to limit the size of an azure blob container?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

In my application, a web service send a shared access signature (write rights on container) to the client so it can upload files.

Is there any way to limit the size (1Gb for instance) of uploaded content ?
The ideal solution would be a custom size limit on the container. Otherwise it could be a limit on the shared access signature.

I could also change my application to send a share access signature on individual blobs if the feature is available on blobs.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Windows Azure does not provide limit per container. The limit provided by Windows Azure is by storage account (100 TB/account) and by individual blob (200 GB max. for a block blob and 1 TB  max. for a page blob). For your requirement, I think you would need to implement this limit in your application.

Comment: We cannot put a limit on writes we are billed for - using a shared access. As you said, I'll have to do it in my application and avoid shared access signature.

Comment: Just an update: the limit of account has been increased to 200TB. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/11/04/windows-azure-s-flat-network-storage-and-2012-scalability-targets.aspx

Comment: Limit is now 500TB. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#storage-limits

Comment: Limit is now 2 PB for US and Europe, 500 TB for all other regions

Comment: it's not 10 yetabytes

Comment: Maximum size of single blob container = Same as maximum storage account capacity = 5 PiB                    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#storage-limits

Answer (score 12):

The concept of trusting the client over the date size to be sent is pretty dangerous, especially for a service that bills depending on the size of the data transferred and stored.

The client could be a public HTML website. Any user who could leak the SAS by calling your service, would be able to send an enormous file.

I think the SAS should specify the maximum size of data that can be read, of written, for a given container / BLOB.

Answer (score -1):

It is typical for someone to have uploads go to the app first, and the app writes the file to the blob itself.  The leased signatures is typically used for read only scenarios.

Comment: That way you need to make your app scalable instead of profiting from the fact that azure storage is scalable.

Comment: for read only scenarios, you would want to use Shared Access Signature Tokens, leasing is to ensure that only one process/executable can read or write the blob at any given time.